# Don't require all the positional arguments if an optional argument is present

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have the following snippet:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("a") # always required
parser.add_argument("x") # don't required in case -t option is chosen
parser.add_argument("y") # don't required in case -t option is chosen
parser.add_argument("z") # don't required in case -t option is chosen
parser.add_argument("-t", "--tt")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The point is, I don't need the positional arguments `x`, `y` and `z` if the `-t` option is specified.

Comment: Can you give some more examples of how you want to call the command?  It seems like x y z are required arguments to -t, not positional arguments in their own right?

Comment: Downvoted because it seems like you could just make the arguments optional, and then if `-t` is not given, manually check for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you want I think using [`parse_known_args`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing). Basically this means you can parse the args partially, once to see if you get `-t` or not, and then again to get the remaining args.

E.g:

#### test.py

```
import argparse

parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser1.add_argument("a")  # always required
parser1.add_argument("-t", "--tt", default=False, action='store_true')
args1 = parser1.parse_known_args()

if args1[0].tt:
    print('got t')
else:
    parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser2.add_argument("x")
    parser2.add_argument("y")
    parser2.add_argument("z")
    args2 = parser2.parse_args(args1[1])
    print('got all args')
```

Call it:

```
$ python test.py a -t
got t
$ python test.py a
usage: test.py [-h] x y z
test.py: error: too few arguments
$ python test.py a b c d
got all args
```

You will probably want to modify the `usage` strings though to make sure you get something sane out. Like this you can build up very powerful CLIs, but with great power comes great responsibility to your users :-).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make named arguments optional depending on whether another argument is supplied or not. You can do it for positional arguments though. Consider this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("a") # always required
parser.add_argument("-t", "--tt", nargs=3)  # Expects 3 arguments if -t
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.tt:
    x, y, z = args.tt
    print(x, y ,z)
```